# Calling ValueTask method from the non async method in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, async-await, valuetask

I have created a `ValueTask` type of method in ASP.NET Core:

```
private async ValueTask<InterceptionResult<int>> SaveChanges(DbContext eventData, InterceptionResult<int> result)
{
    await .... my Code
    return result;
}
```

I am calling this method from a non-async process:

```
public override MyMethod<int> SavingChanges(DbContext eventData, InterceptionResult<int> result)
{
    var interceptionResult = SaveChanges(eventData, result).AsTask();
    return interceptionResult.Result;
}
```

Can you please suggest the correct way of calling the `ValueTask` method from the non-async process in ASP.NET Core?

Comment: Correct way is to make the non-async method to be async.

Comment: SavingChanges, is the override method from the asp.net class where async type is not there.

Comment: What ASP.NET class exactly? Create a non-async version of `ValueTask<InterceptionResult<int>> SaveChanges`.

Comment: Also is there any problem with your current code? Does it work? If it does not - how exactly it does not work?

Comment: This code currently works fine. I want to know if this is the correct approach to call ValueTask method from the non-async method. The exact method is,

public override InterceptionResult<int> SavingChanges(DbContextEventData eventData, InterceptionResult<int> result)
{} 
This is override from the .net class SaveChangesInterceptor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to call a `ValueTask` method from a non-async method is to not to. Just don't do it.

The way you are trying to do it is not good, for two reasons:

1. You're calling `.AsTask()` always. The reason why `ValueTask` exists is so that a new `Task` object does not need to be allocated if the method completes synchronously. But here, you're creating a `Task` anyway, invalidating the benefit of using `ValueTask`.
2. You're using `.Result`, which will lock the current thread until the `Task` completes, invalidating the benefit of using async code and potentially introducing the possibility of deadlocks. See the article [Don't Block on Async Code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)

The correct way is to create a second version that is completely synchronous and call that from `SavingChanges`. This is what Microsoft does when they expose a synchronous and asynchronous version of methods. They don't just call the async version from the synchronous.